# How do I combine 2 MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have an "Inputs" table that looks something like this:

```
id  subId   surveyId    name        val
1   1       1       Ip Addr     123.456.789
2   1       1       Cookie      abcdefghij
3   1       1       Time        2012-06-05 22:14:30
4   2       1       Ip Addr     123.456.789
5   2       1       Time        2012-06-05 22:14:40
```

`subId` is short for Submission Id. I want to get all submissions with a specific `survId` after a specified time. There are 2 steps. First, get all submission ids after a specific time. This can be accomplished like this:

```
SELECT subId FROM Inputs WHERE surveyId=1 AND name='Time' AND val>'2012-06-05 22:14:35';
```

Next, get all of the rows for those submissions:

```
SELECT * FROM Inputs WHERE subId IN (...);
```

When I replace the `...` with the results of the first query, everything works fine. It returns the last 2 rows (id 4 and 5). Here is the `EXPLAIN` of query 1:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      Inputs  range   Inputs_ix1  Inputs_ix1  1030    (null)  3       Using where
```

And query 2:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      Inputs  range   Inputs_ix2  Inputs_ix2  4       (null)  30      Using where
```

When I profile them, they take about 1 millisecond together on 10,000 rows. So far so good. However, I would like to combine them together. Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM Inputs WHERE subId IN (SELECT subId FROM Inputs WHERE surveyId=1 AND name='Time' AND val>'2012-06-05 22:14:35');
```

This takes about 200 milliseconds! I think this is due to a [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=17952). So let's try something else:

```
SELECT (@ids:=subId) FROM Inputs WHERE surveyId=1 AND name='Time' AND val>'2012-06-05 22:14:35';
SELECT @ids;
```

Here, I am trying to make an `@ids` variable with the result of the first query. However, only the last id is stored in the variable. Do MySQL variables not work with arrays?!

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run it as one query: (replace the first queries 'subId' portion with '*' and add a '(NOLOCK)')

```
SELECT * FROM Inputs (NOLOCK) WHERE surveyId=1 AND name='Time' AND val>'2012-06-05 22:14:35';
```

Another option is to use a INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT Inputs2.* 
FROM Inputs AS Inputs1 (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Inputs AS Inputs2 (NOLOCK)
ON Inputs1.subId = Inputs2.subId
WHERE surveyId=1 
AND name='Time' 
AND val>'2012-06-05 22:14:35';
```

I don't know the timing of these options.

Good Luck!

Comment: What exactly does the `(NOLOCK)` do?

Comment: It is a hit to the query engine.  It tells it not to lock the tables when running the query.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx.  It is used in production to allow more queries to access the table at the same time.  The engine otherwise only lets one query access the table at a time.

Comment: Ok. The `(NOLOCK)` doesn't seem to work on my setup. But the `INNER JOIN` query answers my question. Thanks!